# Best way to retrieve a reference field using $lookup in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have two models **Book** and **Author**, Book has reference of Author, suppose an Author got deleted then I only want to retrieve those Books who have an author:

**BookSchema** with these fields

```
name: String,
author: {
  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Author',
  required: [true, 'A book must have an author']
}
```

**AuthorSchema** with these fields

```
name: String
```

I have to do it using $lookup operator. I am able to get the desired result but I don't know if it's a good way. This is my solution:

```
const books = await Book.aggregate([
      {   $lookup: {
          from: 'authors',
          localField: 'author',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'bookAuthor'
          }
      },
      {   $match: {   bookAuthor: { $not: { $size: 0 } }   }   },
      {   $unwind: '$bookAuthor'   },
      {   $project: {
          name: 1,
          bookAuthor: {   name: 1   }
          }
      }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have done everything correct, but you don't need to use the `$match` in second phase of `aggregation` pipeline. `$unwind` will automatically remove the documents with empty `bookAuthor` array, so if there is no `author`, it will be removed after `$unwind` stage.

**Try this:**

```
const books = await Book.aggregate([
  {   $lookup: {
      from: 'authors',
      localField: 'author',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'bookAuthor'
      }
  },
  {   $unwind: '$bookAuthor'   },
  {   $project: {
      name: 1,
      bookAuthor: {   name: 1   }
      }
  }
]);
```

Have a look at this [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8IUoikLhX-a) to see it working